# Access and manage native Eth0 without socket

Tags: c, networking

Do you know a manner to access and manage in c interface eth0 without socket???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do something along the lines of invoking the **ifconfig** command on the shell within your C code:

```
system("ifconfig eth0 ...");
```

This will eliminate the need to have a file descriptor but allows you to manage the device using the command. Do a **man ifconfig** to see how to structure your **ifconfig** request to manage whatever you need to do with the interface.

If you need to go lower level than that, then you could simply open up a raw socket...assign the index of the Ethernet device you want to manipulate...and then use your **ioctl()**'s to configure as required:

```
if ((fd = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW)) == -1) {
  perror("socket");
}

struct ifreq req;
strncpy(req.ifr_name, "eth0", IFNAMSIZ-1);
if (ioctl(fd, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifreq) < 0)
  perror("SIOCGIFINDEX");
```

Then you have your handle to **eth0**...

Comment: Agreed...but I don't understand the aversion to using file descriptors here...anyways the first snippet of code (sans socket implementation) could be all he needs to do.

Comment: Agreed, the OP doesn't seem to want to share enough information to really answer the question...

Comment: i want create a gateway for permitt to interact a 6lowpan network and bluetooth network. For this project i must access to eth0 to lower level. I know the solution with raw socket but i ask another solution if exist. Excusme for my confusion information!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can talk directly to the network interface driver through the appropriate `ioctl` calls. Refer to your driver API reference for details. Some OS may provide access through their own API as well, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380990/network-interface-settings).

Comment: Ok but in the ioctl i send the file descriptor. Without socket which fd should i use?

Comment: @user1307697 you realize that noone can answer you without you telling us at least what operating system you're using, right? Try /dev/eth0, to begin with.

Comment: @user1307697 then /dev/eth0 it is:-) Won't help you much without knowing how to talk to the driver though.

Comment: excuse for my confusion information but i a  novel user of programming in linux :) however thank you :)

Comment: Another problem, in /dev/ i don't have eth0...where are is it?

Comment: @user1307697 try /sys/class/net